# Eclipse Create your own system.out.println shortcut

Tags: java, eclipse

How can I *change* the keyboard shortcut in eclipse from sysout + control space to sout + enter like in sublime.

Comment: Eclipse already has the (sysout + control space) to System.out.println()

Comment: yes i would like to change it to sout + enter like i said in my post @GBlodgett

Comment: `sysout` can be changed to `sout` in _Window > Preferences: Java > Editor > Templates_. There's probably a plug-in for Enter instead of Ctrl+Space.

Comment: You can type any subset of the characters s-y-s-o-u-t and get a list of possible template matches. Hence **syso** or **sout** followed by CTL/space, followed by enter (to select the topmost entry from the list of matches) has the same effect as **sysout** then CTL/space. Actually, since **sysout** is the only possible match for **ysou** you can type **ysou** then CTL/space instead of **sysout** then CTL/space - the effect is identical.

Comment: Offensive but possibly more-helpful-than-you'd-expect tip: In IntelliJ you can define your "Live Templates" freely ([screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/IxGbFZW.png)) - e.g. by default, enter "sout" and press Tab. The Community Edition of IntelliJ is free even for commercial development. I don't know how much Eclipse has changed in the last 4 years when I changed to IntelliJ, but personally, as a pure Java developer, I am really glad I made the switch. Download link: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How can I change the keyboard shortcut in eclipse from sysout +
>   control space to sout + enter like in sublime.

The short answer is you can't. But you can modify an existing template, or add a new template, to create a shortcut of **sout** that will generate

```
System.out.println();
```

To do that:

- Select **Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Templates**.
- Scroll down the list of existing templates and select the one named **sysout**.
- Click the **Edit...** button.
- Change the **Name** field from **sysout** to **sout**, and click **OK**.
- You will be invited to either replace **sysout** with **sout**, or add **sout** as a new template. Pick whichever option is appropriate.

That's all there is to it. In the editor you can now type **sout** and press <kbd>Ctl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to generate

```
System.out.println();
```

However, there is no real need to do any of that because when you press <kbd>Ctl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> after typing **sout** the template **sysout**  is offered as the first possible match:

[image: soutMatches]

So without making any changes to Eclipse you can type **sout** and press <kbd>Ctl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>, then <kbd>Enter</kbd> (to select the first entry in the dropdown list) to almost achieve what you want.

While editing in Eclipse it is not possible to have any action triggered simply by pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. That's because the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key already has a well defined function: to move to the next line, taking any text with it that is to the right of the cursor.

If you could generate `System.out.println();` just by typing **sout** and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> you wouldn't be able to create a line containing only **sout**.

Comment: For some reason the option to print to standard out shows up at the bottom of the autocompletion list instead of the top. Is there any way to fix that?